# Building Rest API response Object based on consumers requests

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building rest API & below are my end points.

```
EndPoint 1:

/products/{code} --> giving product inforamtion

Endpoint 2:

/products/{code}/packages --> provides packages for a given productcode

Endpoint 3:

/products/{code}/suppliers --> provides suppliers for a given product code

Endpoint 4:

/products/{code}/shelfTags --> provides shelfTags for a given product code
```

We have multiple down stream systems(more than 20 downstream systems) which require products & it's related information.

**Note:** Not all users require the nested collection information, some clients need only product information and they are good and below are the combinations and it varies by consumers

```
1.  product info only --> **consumer 1**
2.  product ,  packages --> **consumer 2**
3.  product, suppliers, packages--> **consumer 3**
4.  product, supplier, packages, shelfTags--> **consumer 4**
5.  product, supplier, shelfTags --> **consumer 5**
6.  product, shelfTags --> **consumer 6**
7.  etc...
```

From above example, **consumer 4** makes Http call to get product code and now has to make multiple Http calls to get packages (Endpoint 2) or suppliers (Endpoint 3) or shelfTags (Endpoint 4) etc... Is this a good design ?

Is there a way consumers can get only **what they want in response** on one request ? (Now is it a good design to give data needs in one request ? or it's good to ask consumers to make multiple Http calls to get nested collection ?)

**Note :** I cannot include all nested collection along with Products Endpoint 1 itself as it's requires huge data querying so I am planning to only provide what consumer may need, that will reduce unnecessary querying and also providing irrelevant information to few consumers who don't need that data.

**Current Design:**

I have below now:

Approach 1:

```
/products/{code}?Options = packages, Suppliers
```

Above would give Product details and have options query parameter based on that I can decide whether to pass Packages & supplier, shelftags etc, but here we are not filtering on resource to pass query parameter, I believe this is not a good approach as query params are only used to filter on the resources.

Approach 2:

Form a different endpoint as query parameter on the resource is for only filters  if I am not wrong so looking at below option:

```
/products/{code}/extendedProductDetails?Options = Packages, Suppliers
```

In option2 extendedProductDetails is an operation rather than resource itself and I am filtering on the operation.

Can anyone provide solution on how to solve this requirement

Comment: Sounds like an ideal use case for [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) but that might be a step too far for your org.

Comment: @IanMercer true we current don't use GraphQL :(, what would be a solution for above requirement, I had two approaches above and not sure which one to use please suggest

Comment: Take a look at [OData](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/understand-odata-in-6-steps/) too for another approach to solving this problem. I'm not a fan but you should compare it to your ideas rather than inventing something new.

Comment: to what use will the client put the information in, e.g. /products/{code}?Options = packages, Suppliers. The base resource is a product but the client wants a related resource, which is a product and its suppliers. What is the domain name of that resource? e.g. OrderPreparation resource? The API is there to support the business so can work at the domain level where product is the simplest type of resource the business deals with. What other types of resources does the business support? e.g. what will a client do with a product and its suppliers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Approach 1* vs. *Approach 2***

Assuming that you want to use REST, from my point of view, between the options you gave, I would go with something like *Approach 2*, since it is a proper collection for extended information. However, I think I'd prefer to model it such as `/products-extended/{code}?options=packages,suppliers`, since it defines a different collection.

Besides enhancing the readability of the API, in this way, you have the `products` collection and the `products-extended` collection: each of them can be consumed independently and with different query string filters (of course that less filtering is prone to increase complexity and latency, but in my opinion, query string parameters should be optional). If they *must really not* be optional and there is always the need to provide a `product id` and at least one nested collection, then, you can also consider designing something like `products-extended/{code}/{packages,suppliers,etc}`. Either way, this would "protect" your `products` collection.

Moreover, this would allow you to perform different operations (POST, PUT,...) to both collections, if your use case requires such.

**Other approaches**

Besides the other suggestions on GraphQL - would be great, yes :) -, OData or the custom types, couldn't you keep only with the individual collections? Depending on your use case, maybe you could perform parallel calls to `/products/{code}/packages`, `/products/{code}/suppliers` and so on, since you already know the `product id`. Perhaps, the major drawback of this design would be, for example, to create new products. However, the GET requests became super easy :)

Comment: Thanks N Pinheiro it helps, I was out for sometime, now how can I assign bounty points to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution would be to use custom media types in the request header:

```
application/json+info-only
application/json+supplier
application/json+supplier+packages
etc.
```

In your controller action you would check for the selected media type and respond to the request based on them. Simply return an IActionResult and your consumer will get the data within one request.

It's very similar to your approaches but with custom extended media types you would have still one endpoint without additional parameters.